# How should the CIM_DataFile file name be passed to an inline ActiveScriptEventConsumer VBScript for a __InstanceCreationEvent WMI subscription?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I need to automate moving a file when created from one directory and only the file that triggered the event...not every file in the directory.

I am trying to setup a WMI subscription using powershell and the ActiveScriptEventConsumer with an inline VBScript where I can pass the name of the file to the inline VBScript.

```
    PS> $evtConsumer.ScriptText = "WITH CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"") 
    >> .MoveFile """ $EventArgs.NewEvent.Name """, ""[target path here]""
    >> END WITH"
```

When I request the $evtConsumer.ScriptText the below is returned in the console

```
    PS> $evtConsumer.ScriptText
    WITH CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    .MoveFile "", "[target path]"
    END WITH
```

Not surprisingly, nothing happens when I create a file in the targeted directory.

Answer (score 1):

This sets up a WMI subscription using VBScript.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set MonitoredEvents = WMI.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""C:\\\\Scripts""'")
Do
    WMIPath = Split(MonitoredEvents.NextEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent, "=")(1)
    FilePath = Replace(WMIPath, "\\", "\")
'   FSO.CopyFile  filepath, "C:\", vbtrue 
    wscript.echo filepath
Loop
```

If you want your program to act service like. In Windows you use Task Scheduler, which you choose you or another user. Note if you configure it to run when you are not logged in it will be invisible to you when you are logged in. Windows has inbuilt security accounts for programs/services like this.

*About Task Scheduler* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page

*About Service Accounts* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/service-user-accounts

Comment: CatCat thanks for the post.  Does this create a permanent WMI subscription to the event?  I can get this to work on a temporary WMI subscription.

Comment: The file loops until you kill it.

Comment: Ok so if I execute the above and then close out my session or even logoff the server altogether the script will continue to run?

Comment: If you configure it that way. Its just a program.

Comment: Thanks catcat.  I am new to using WMI however and not sure what you mean by "configuring it that way".  How would I configure the above script to persist outside of my specific session?

Comment: In Windows you use Task Scheduler, which you choose you or another user. Note if you configure it to run when you are not logged in it will be invisible to you when you are logged in. Windows has inbuilt security accounts for programs/services like this. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/service-user-accounts for options.