# Trigger email if any new file is created greater than a specific size

Tags: batch-file

Everyday a new file is added to `C:\Perflogs`, the file is named according to the current date, e.g. `01162019_Logs.txt`.

If the new file is added, I need to check the size of it and trigger an email if it's greater than `40 bytes`.

I want to run a batch file, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: _"I don't know how to do this"_ is fine, we all learn, but you at the very least need to try something, fail, then bring that attempt here and show how you failed. We do not write code for free here, we help people with the problems they experience with their code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225532/how-should-the-cim-datafile-file-name-be-passed-to-an-inline-activescripteventco/54225670#54225670

Comment: Apologies, I have tried folder monitor and some other apps to do this but it didn’t help. I’m new to do this. I have a beginner level experience and this was difficult for me. Sorry for the trouble. I’ll try this from my end. Thank you for the swift response.